# how to add my one project jar in another maven project in netbeans

Tags: spring, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have one project jar oauth.
I want to add it in another maven project . I tried to change pom.xml file but no effect. Can anyone please suggest me?

I tried to add following dependency in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.payupaisa.oauth</groupId>
  <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapps/WEB-INF/lib/auth.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have give the correct artifactId ? it is auth or oauth ?
    `<artifactId>auth</artifactId>`
What is the error you are getting ??

Comment: my jar name is auth.jar so i gave auth as artifactId

Comment: I am not able to import any class of this auth project.

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that you have that auth.jar in your local repository (as it builds fine).

Why don't you give a try like this.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.payupaisa.oauth</groupId>
  <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Honestly speaking I don't prefer to give the jar location in my pom file and using scope as system, I leave this task to handle by Maven to resolve all the artifacts either by searching in local maven repository first(/.m2) or in MAVEN CENTRAL REPO if it is a 3rd party jar.

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>com.payupaisa.oauth</groupId>
      <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>   This & after changing folders names in /.m2 folder,it helped Thanks